# Magento 2 How to add time to date filters in UiComponents

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have a field that uses time (hours, minuets) as well as a date on my grid component.

I'm trying to filter by time on the admin panel.

This is what I want:

[image: Time Filter]

But I want it for the filters above the uiCompenent Grid:

[image]

Adding the following code to each `<column>` node (where dates apply) didn't do the trick, which I guess was expected:

```
<item name="options" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm</item>
    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? i need the same